# problems with join

Tags: sql, oracle

List the ingredient id, name, date ordered, quantity & unit (in one column) for all ingredients, even if the ingredient has not been ordered (Hint: use outer join)

```
SELECT ingredient_id, ingredient_name, date_ordered, CONCAT(quantity, unit) AS "Quantity & Unit" 
FROM ingredient ing 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ingredient_purchase_list ing2 ON ing.ingredient_id = ing2.ingredient_id 
ORDER BY ingredient_id;
```

(keep saying column ambiguously defined)

Comment: What issue you are facing? add some sample data with your expected output.

Comment: I cannot find the problem it keep saying "column ambiguously defined"

Comment: just use aliases before column names - ing and ing2.

Answer (score 2):

specify your table `alias` on your `columns`.

```
SELECT ing.ingredient_id, ing.ingredient_name, ing2.date_ordered, CONCAT(ing2.quantity, ing2.unit) AS "Quantity & Unit" 
FROM ingredient ing 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ingredient_purchase_list ing2 ON ing.ingredient_id = ing2.ingredient_id 
ORDER BY ing.ingredient_id;
```

Comment: I new i missed some ing2 somewhere in the code but couldn't understand where ! thank you Sir ! I added and delete them to see if worked, the one i posted wasn't complete for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

Looking from your query, It seems like you must be getting issue of column names.

You need to give alias to the columns as following:

> ```
> SELECT ing.ingredient_id, ing.ingredient_name, ing2.date_ordered, CONCAT(ing2.quantity, ing2.unit) AS "Quantity & Unit" 
> FROM ingredient ing 
> LEFT OUTER JOIN ingredient_purchase_list ing2 ON ing.ingredient_id = ing2.ingredient_id 
> ORDER BY ing.ingredient_id;
> ```

Cheers!!